# Postbox no longer displays my Account subfolders

Tags: email, imap, postbox

Problem:

Since updating to 3.0.11 I've found that all of my sub-folders have disappeared.

Ordinarily clicking my gmail  account under 'All Accounts' I could then see a set of folders in the lower pane:

Inbox
Sent
Drafts
Amazon Purchases
etc...

However, this is no longer the case. I now have just the main inbox with no entries in the lower pane.

I have attempted the following to no avail:

- [Subscribing to folders](http://support.postbox-inc.com/hc/en-us/articles/202200530-Subscribing-to-IMAP-Folders)
- [Subscribing to folders again under a different link)...](http://support.postbox-inc.com/hc/en-us/articles/202198250-Unable-to-find-your-IMAP-mail-folders-after-install-) Option 2 here isn't possible as the 'IMAP Server Directory' checkbox doesn't exist
- [Mapping Labels](http://support.postbox-inc.com/hc/en-us/articles/202200490-Using-Gmail-with-Postbox-3)

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're set to use POP3 as your question doesn't say but suggests, then you won't ever get additional folders. IMAP is what you need, it's unclear (since I don't use Postbox) whether the box you mention doesn't exist because you haven't selected IMAP or if you're unable to choose IMAP.

Comment: @Tyson, everything is configured for IMAP. Both on the client (incoming and outgoing) and on the server.

Comment: @Tyson here's the first: http://support.postbox-inc.com/hc/en-us/articles/202198250-Unable-to-find-your-IMAP-mail-folders-after-install-

Comment: Here's the second: http://support.postbox-inc.com/hc/en-us/articles/202200490-Using-Gmail-with-Postbox-3

Answer (score 0):

I found that in order to get my folders back I had to:

1. Uninstall Postbox
2. Delete the profile data.

Uninstalling was pretty easy. Drag and drop to the trash, then empty the trash.

Deleting the profile data although easy was troublesome to do as the profile folder *seemed* to be hidden. Although that could be just me.

Go to terminal and type

`cd ~/Library/Application\ Support`

then:

`rm -r /Postbox`